# how to save a data to backend thrhough controller from selecting a dropdown list in the website odoo 12?

Tags: javascript, xml, odoo

Ive been trying to take a user input from the dropdown list and update it to the backend through controller.i will explain my code below,

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $(".form-group input").hide() //hide inputs
        $(".edit_save").click(function() {
          var selector = $(this).closest(".form-group")
          var btnText = $(this).text();
          if (btnText === 'Edit') {
            $(this).text('Save');
            $(this).next("button").show(); //hide
            selector.find("form span").hide() //span hide
            selector.find("form input").show() //show inputs
          } else {
            $(this).text('Edit');
            $(this).next("button").hide();
            selector.find("form span").show()
            selector.find("form input").hide()

            var blood_group = document.getElementById("blood_group").value;

            ajax.jsonRpc("/my/health-record-save", 'call', {
                        'sex': sex,
            });
           selector.find("span.blood_group").text(blood_group)
          }

        });
```

XML

```
<div class="form-group">
  <form class="form-horizontal" style="bg-light">
     <t>
      <button type="button" class="edit_save">Edit</button>
      <button class="cancel" type="button" style="display:none">Cancel</button>
    </t>
    <div class="col-md text-md-left" style="padding-top:10px">
      <label class="text-secondary" for="blood_group"><strong>Blood group:</strong></label>
          <select name="blood_group" id="blood_group">
               <option>
                    <t t-esc ="hr.blood_group"/>
                </option>
                <option value="o+">O+</option>
                <option value="o-">O-</option>
                <option value="a+">A+</option>
                <option value="a-">A-</option>
                <option value="b-">B-</option>
                <option value="b+">B+</option>
                <option value="ab+">AB+</option>
                <option value="ab-">AB-</option>
          </select>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

controller.py

```
@http.route(['/my/health-record-save'], type='json', auth="public", website=True)
    def portal_save_health_record(self, **kw):
        health_record_id = kw.get('h_record')
        blood_group = kw.get('blood_group')
        health_record = request.env['health.record'].search([('id', '=', health_record_id)])
        health_record.write({
            'blood_group': blood_group,
        })
        return request.redirect('/my/health-record')
```

What my concern is i dont know how to give the input class to `<select>` `<option>` dropdown list and make it to save to the backend through controller when the user click the button named `save`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's based on how you are render the view through-  JS or controller.

Any way you should get hr.blood_group as a dictionary like - {'o+':"O+",..}

then you can replace the option as below code.

```
<t t-set="blood_group" t-value="hr.blood_group"/>
<option t-foreach="blood_group" t-as="bgroup" t-att-value="bgroup">
   <t t-esc="blood_group[bgroup]"/>
</option>
```

This is the base reference I can give, if you have any queries comment below.

Also, I'm adding a reference link from the website, take a look at it.

**https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/7ddf36474596ec5213aba7b892c1a62998c99da9/addons/website/static/src/xml/website.contentMenu.xml#L28**

Comment: Thankyou for sharing the knowledge,Appreciated.

Comment: Share it please